# C# - Swap 2 sides of an '=' operator

Tags: regex, visual-studio, text-editor

how can I swap the expressions on either side of an '=' operator?

for example I have:

```
a.Text = b.ID;
```

I need a Regx to change sides:

```
b.ID = a.Text;
```

I want to use the regx in **Replace window of Visual Studio**
in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Visual Studio "Replace In Files" dialog, enter `([^= ]*) = ([^= ]*);` in the "Find what" text box and `$2 = $1;` in the "Replace with" dialog. For example, in Visual Studio 2012:

[image]

Comment: @Reza You have already marked another answer as the correct one despite it not answering the question. Anyway, the VS 2010 syntax is slightly different. Replace the "Replace With" text with `\2 = \1;`

Comment: at first he didnt answer the qustion. but he edited it and add the correct answer. but your answer is perfectly better. I accept yours

Answer (score 5):

In C# you can do it using code like this:

```
var text = "a.Text = b.ID;";
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<left>[^=\s]+)\s*=\s*(?<right>[^;]+);$");
var match = regex.Match(text);
if (match.Success) {
  var newText = String.Format(
    "{0} = {1};", match.Groups["right"].Value, match.Groups["left"].Value);
}
```

Breakdown of the regular expression:

- `^`: Anchor the match at the start of the string
- `(?<left>[^=\s]+)`: Match at least one character that is not `=` or whitespace. Capture it to a group named `left`.
- `\s*=\s*`: Match `=` optionally surrounded by whitespace.
- `(?<right>[^;]+)`: Match at least one character that is not `;`. Capture it to a group named `right`.
- `;`: Match `;`.
- `$`: Anchor the match to the end of the string.

---

If you want to perform a similar replacement in the Visual Studio editor you need use the following values in the **Quick Replace** dialog box:

- **Find what**: `{[^=:b]+}:b*=:b*{[^;]+}`
- **Replace with**: `\2 = \1`
- **Use**: Regular expressions

The major difference is that groups are defined by brackets, not parenthesis and the whitespace character group is expressed by `:b`, not `\s`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's *an* idea:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var regex = new Regex("([^=]*) = ([^;]*);");
        string input = "a.Text = b.ID;";
        string output = regex.Replace(input, "$2 = $1;");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Note that this preserves the space each side of the `=` and also the semi-colon at the end - but it does *require* those things as well. Basically, your code needs to do more than just "switch the text before and after =".

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesized groups, for example:

```
string input = "a.Text = b.ID;";
Regex regex = new Regex("([^=]*)[=]([^=]*);");
regex.Replace(input, "$2 = $1;");
```

Comment: tnx. but I want to use the regx in Replace window of Visual Studio

Comment: @Reza I have added a new answer below. Hopefully, this helps.